# I cannot understand what is `Null` in Dart

Tags: c#, oop, scala, dart, type-systems

I cannot understand what is `Null` in Dart.

In C# language `null` is  a literal. The `null` is the default value of reference-type variable.

The `null` in C# has no type. It is not possible to access members of `null` through the dot `.`.

Example:

```csharp
String s = null; // the default value of reference-type variable
null.GetType(); // Operator '.'  cannot be applied to operand of the type <null>
```

In Dart the `null` has a type `Null`. But instance of `Null` type in Dart is not a `bottom` type.

How this works in Dart according to the type inheritance?

```dart
// How the `null` value with type of `Null`
// can be assigned to a `String` type?
String s = null;
```

This code produce strange warning in Dart Editor.

```dart
"Tests for null should be done with '== null'".
print(s is NUll);
```

But I don't want "tests for `null`". I want test for `Null`. This is not the same.

Why this strange warning in Dart Editor?

I want test how to work Dart type system but the Editor get me this message.

I not understand it because I cannot understand how the `Null` type at the same time:

1. can be subtype of all types
2. can be not a subtype of all types

I welcome the answers from developers.

Is there any magic which is contrary to the object-oriented programming (that not documented in Dart language specification) about how the incompatible types can be assumed as the compatible types?

P.S.

The `Null` type in Dart is complete class and thus it is a `regular type`.

I not found official documentation which says the opposite (that `Null` type is not a `regular` type but it is a `bottom` type).

Here's proof of my words.

```dart
class Null {
  factory Null._uninstantiable() {
    throw new UnsupportedError('class Null cannot be instantiated');
  }

  /** Returns the string `"null"`. */
  String toString() => "null";
}
```

You can see that `Null` is not a `bottom` type.

Here you can see that `null` is not a `bottom` type but a `Null` type.

```dart
print(null.runtimeType == Null);
```

```dart
true
```

P.S.

I do not understand why some people do not understand the problems and lead contradictory examples.

```
The static type of null is bottom.
```

Not right. Type of `null` is `Null` type but not a `bottom` type.

I have already given proof that

- `null.runtimeType == Null` but not a `bottom` type
- Class `Null` is not `bottom` type (see source code in SDK).

P.S.

Why all of these answers with not correspond to reality (runtime) conclusions?

Or may be opponents are not developrers?

Or may be Dart runtime not follows language specification and opponents believe (or not know?) that this rule is not respected?

I think that `null` must have type of `_Null` that not declared in source code but `created internally in virtual machine`.

In this case I cannot say that `_Null` is not a `bottom` type because this hidden in virtual machine.

Who right? Me or you?

Answer (score 8):

From the [spec](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.gianetx6ltsy)

> Null
>
> The reserved word null denotes the null object.
>
> nullLiteral:
>        null
>
> ;
>
> The null object is the sole instance of the built-in class Null.
>   Attempting to instantiate Null causes a runtime error. It is a
>   compile-time error for a class to attempt to extend or implement Null.
>   Invoking a method on null yields a NoSuchMethodError unless the method
>   is explicitly implemented by class Null.
>
> The static type of null is bottom.
>
> The decision to use bottom instead of Null allows null to be be
>   assigned everywhere without complaint by the static checker.

bottom is poorly documented and I cannot find much reference to it. However, when the spec discusses [void](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.a5hjb7g00phr) it is mentioned that :

> bottom is a subtype of all types

So, to answer your questions, it would appear that there is nothing magical about the Null type but there is magic going on with the null literal; it has a type of bottom, which means it is a subtype of all types.

Since `null` is the only instance of `Null`, it is more correct to check if something `== null` than `is Null`, which I assume is why you get that warning from the editor.

Comment: Your words "Since null is the only instance of Null". I not understands you. What is correct? 1. The static type of null is bottom? Or 2. null is the instance of Null? Or "static type" is not the same as type of value? How "null" can be "Null" and "bottom" at the same time? The "bottom" not means "Null". The "bottom" means a subtype of all types. That is, null is a "bottom" but not "Null". Why need "Null" if "null" is a "bottom" but not "Null"? "Null" is not a "bottom". It is a regular class.

Comment: At compile-time, the analyzer treats null as "bottom" only to eliminate type warnings... its runtimeType is Null, and it is an instance of class Null

Comment: @Ganymede But Null is not a String. How it works? How not String assigned to String.

Comment: You are confusing types with classes. The class of `null` is `Null`, the type of `null` is `bottom`. Classes and types are completely different things, they have nothing to do with each other. In OO, classes define representation, types define behavior.

Comment: @ Jörg W Mittag You himself understands you? The class of null is Null. Class is a declaration. Class is not a type. Class is a container of declarations. Type gets info from class declaration or directly from VM. In Dart the values does not have inforamtion about classes. They have information about types. Classes only in your source code and also they mirrored in reflection. In runtime only types even info compiler get for types from classes. "The class of null is Null" is not right. "The null is Null". It may extends Null or implements Null. But Null is not an instance of a class at runtime

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag And also I am not confusing types with classes. Types in Dart can be internal and constructed from  the class declarations. You confusing with types and with classes in Dart. Classes only for declarations. They not instantiated as types. Most of types in Dart are based on classes but not vice versa as you say.

Comment: That's interesting. I never heard of the type `bottom` before.

Comment: The `bottom` name is not good but this is reasonable. Some languages ​​have similar types. But in Dart only `null` is instance of `bottom`. But problem in that the `Null` type in Dart is not a `bottom` alias. The `Null` is a regular type. In this case, if type of null (actually) is `Null` but not a `bottom` this fact contradict object-oriented single inheritance principle in Dart. This behavior of `Null` not explained very well language spec. The "null is String" in Dart false. How null can be assigned to String if it is not String? Also if `null` is `bottom` then why `null` is not a String?

Comment: Again: the runtime type of `null` is `Null`. The static type of `null` (i.e. the one checked at compile time) is bottom, subtype of all types. This is specifically done so that `null` can be assigned to String.

Comment: The runtime type of `null` is `Null` but `Null` is not a `bottom`. See source code in SDK. Value of  type `Null` is not a subtype of `String`. Where proof of your words that `Null` is a subtype of all types? I give proof that `Null` is NOT a subtype of all types.

Comment: May be you forgotten that dart has not only `compile time checker`. It also has `runtime type checker`. At runtime `null` is not a value of `bottom` (as assumed at compile type) but a value of `Null` type. In language specification `Null` not described as the `bottom` type (subtype of all type). And in practice (see source code) the `Null` class declared as regular type. I not ask about compilation. I ask about how at runtime value of regular type `Null` can be assigned to incompatible types?

Comment: According to [Gilad](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/optional-types/), on variable assignment, the static type checker checks that the runtimeType of the object is a subtype of the static type of the variable. As @mezoni points out, the runtimeType of `null` is `Null` which is not assignable to `String`, so why doesn't the static checker complain about this if running in checked mode? There must be more to the story than what I've posted in my answer.

Comment: @PixelElephant This is Gilad words which remained empty words without action. I am talked abour this problem here but people not understands. "I believe we want to hide Null from users so they cannot write x is Null, allowing some optimizations to be undetectable by user code. And so Null might in practice be implemented as a private class, or even kept entirely hidden inside the implementation of the VM or dart2js. We still need to decide how to safely expose it in the mirror system."

Comment: @PixelElephant Dart language and `dart:core` has a lot of similar problems. No one would use such a software product in major projects as long as it is based on the magic but not on predictable behavior. Where warranty that there is no hidden bugs if this functionality based on the magic but not on simple logic (source code -> grammar -> compiler -> runtime)?

Answer (score 3):

`Null` is a subtype of `Object` and as Dart is a dynamic language assigning `null` (an instance of `Null`) to a variable of type `String` or any other type is valid.
The static type checking must have a special rule to not produce an error or warning for assigning `null` to a variable of another type.

Checking for `s is Null` results to `true` but the Dart style guide seems to mandate `s == null` for a reason unknown to me (maybe it's faster).

Comment: Dart is not a dynamic language. Dart is language with optional typing. This is not the same as dynamic language (for example, Ruby). Assigning an instance of Null to a variable of type String or any other type is NOT valid in Dart. Because Null is not a subtype of String. This is magic. Value of bottom type can be assigned to any type. This is correct. But value of Null cannot be be assigned to any type. Magic rules is not serious. The bottom is not supertype but a subtype. That is, bottom is Null : true. Null is bottom : false. Null is String : false.

Comment: Java and C# are not a dynamic languages. But "eval" functionality can be emulated (written by hand) and you can execute string in this languages. This can be done via Compiler Services. But what you never have in this languages (becuase they not dynamic) it is a possibility add/remove declarations in existing declarations. That is not possible add a member to existing type in not dynamic language. You may only add new declartions but this not required to call these languages as a dynamic because this can be done via compiler service but not via modification of existing types.